# The Submit Button doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox, but Works in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, submit

I had a situation where the Submit Button would not work if you clicked on it in Firefox and Chrome, but it worked as it should in Internet Explorer.

Even odder, I found that I could "tab" to the button and hit enter and it would work. This was a portion of the form code:

```
<form id="product_form" name="product_form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateProductForm();" action="product-photo-mail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>  
        <td class = "left_side" width="30%">Quantity:</td>
        <td class = "right_side" width="60%">
            <select name = "quantity_cards">

                <option>50</option>
                <option>75</option>
                <option>100</option>
                <option>125</option>
                <option>150</option>
                <option>more</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    .
    .
    .


    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">You're almost done!</td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><br />After you submit your order we will send over your digital proof for approval!</td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" class="formbutton" value="Submit My Order" />
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
</form>`
```

When I moved the button above the text, it worked on all browsers as I would expect. I have no idea why this would happen. I spent hours trying to get this to work and the only thing I could get to work is swapping the order:

```
    .
    .

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" class="formbutton" value="Submit My Order" />
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">You're almost done!</td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><br />After you submit your order we will send over your digital proof for approval!</td>
   </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

I would like to have the text first and the submit button, but I am at my wits end here. Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<button>` tag instead of `<input>`.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Stephane Delcroix is not a mod, so I don't see any need to take his unsolicited policing on board. In my opinion, I think he is indulging an ego-trip.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to provide a link?

Is there not perhaps an hidden element that is covering your submit button? That would explain why you can tab to the button, but not click it.